# Access Textbox Custom Number Format

Tags: ms-access

I am from Bangladesh and in Bangladesh comma (,) is used as thousand separator. We use comma after 3 digit, 5 digit, 7 digit from right to left like `9,999`, `99,999`, `9,99,999`,`99,99,999`,`9,99,99,999` & `99,99,99,999`. I was trying to accomplish this format by textbox format property. When I use `#,##0` as format then it only format till 5 digit. When number is 6 digit or higher then it only shows one comma like `456,456` while expected is `4,56,456`. I have tried to use `#,##,##,##0` but it automatically goes to `#,##0`. So, how can I format the text box to get my desired result as below?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You'll have to run a custom format like this:

```
TextValue = Format(Fix(Value), Left("##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,", -Int(-(Len(Abs(Fix(Value))) - 2) \ 2) * 4) & "##0")
```

Note, the negative values will be formatted correctly as well while decimals will be cut off.

If you have decimals, append these:

```
TextValue = Format(Fix(Value), Left("##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,", -Int(-(Len(Abs(Fix(Value))) - 2) \ 2) * 4) & "##0") & LTrim(Str(Abs(CCur(Value)-Fix(Value))))
```

As used as *ControlSource* (read-only) in a form or a report:

```
=Format(Fix([Amount]),Left("##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,",-Int(-(Len(Abs(Fix([Amount])))-2)\2)*4) & "##0")
```

**Addendum**:

To cover any situation with values:

1. Larger than 1, with or without decimals
2. Smaller than 1, a positive decimal value
3. Zero
4. Larger than -1, a negative decimal value
5. Smaller than -1, with or without decimals

an extended expression is needed:

```vb
TextValue = Format(Value, ";-") & _
    Format(Abs(Fix(Value)), Left("##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,", -Int(-(Len(CStr(Abs(Fix(Value)))) - 2) \ 2) * 4) & "##0") & _
    IIf(Value - Fix(Value), LTrim(Str(Abs(Value - Fix(Value)))), "")
```

1. First part controls the sign
2. Second part controls the integer value
3. Third part controls decimals

This will output correctly for any value within the entire range of Currency.

Comment: I will try your answer tomorrow and feedback. So, if I use this `On_Current` event of form and report, will it work as regulat?

Comment: Yes. Also, see extended answer, please.

Comment: In this case I have to use another textbox to formatted display result, right?

Comment: I can meet my requirement of project by this. Accepting the answer. Thanks for your efforts.